# Libmysqld Crashes On Start

Tags: mysql, c, crash, mysql-error-1146

I tried to create a very simple application using the MySQL embedded server.
I basically took the simple example from the MySQL documentation and modified it a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "mysql.h"

MYSQL *mysql;

static char *server_options[] = { "mysql_test", "--datadir=/Users/admin/libmysqldtest", "--language=/Users/admin/libmysqldtest/german", NULL };
int num_elements = (sizeof(server_options) / sizeof(char *)) - 1;

static char *server_groups[] = { "libmysqld_server", "libmysqld_client", NULL };

int main(void)
{
    mysql_library_init(num_elements, server_options, server_groups);
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "libmysqld_client");
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

    //Do some queries here...

    mysql_close(mysql);
    mysql_library_end();

    return 0;
}
```

On start-up

```
mysql_embedded: Unknown error 1146
```

is logged and `InnoDB` initializes.
Afterwards the app crashes at `mysql_init`.
Linking against libmysqld-debug I get the following error message:

```
Assertion failed: (argc && *argc >= 1), function handle_options, file 
/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-3198286-1302522144.5/mysql-5.5.12/mysys/my_getopt.c, line 167
```

I use the static libmysqld(-debug) library distributed with the community server TAR-Archive for Mac OS X from the MySQL website (64 bit).

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem but you don't need the NULL at the end of the `server_options` array since you pass the number of elements in this array in as the first argument. It's only needed for the groups array.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, as the number of arguments is correct.

Comment: @Kiril: That's precisely why I said I didn't think it was related.